# JsonPath with JsonTextReader: Token at a Time

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath, jsonreader, jpath

I am having an issue with JsonPath working differently when loading token (.Load) at a time using JsonTextReader versus loading the entire JSON using ReadFrom.  Here is an example:
JSON: Path="[*].person" Method=SelectTokens(path)

```
 [
  {
    "person": {
      "personid": 123456
    }
  },
  {
    "person": {
      "personid": 798
    }
  }
]
```

When using .ReadFrom, it'll return the proper 2 elements.  If I use .Load though, it'll return 0 elements. However, if I change the path to "**person**", .ReadFrom returns 0 elements while .Load returns 2 elements.

As a fix, I could change the path so that it'll remove up to the first "." i.e. **path = substring(path.index(".")+1);** however, this feels more of a hack than a proper fix.  I would, of course, also need to ensure that the JSON is an array, but in most of my cases, it would be.

So finally, I am trying to learn how to use JSON Path with arrays when loading a token at a time. Any recommendations?

[Full Code](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Json/JsonExtractor.cs)

[Full JSON](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/Samples/Blogs/MRys/JSON/complex.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in the code you have linked to is it reads tokens until it encounters an object, it then loads the a `JToken` from this object, which reads ahead to the end of this object.
So what you end up with is a `JToken` per item in the root array. You can then for each `JToken` call:

```
token.SelectTokens("person").OfType<JObject>()
```

cause you know the property contains an object.

That is the equivalent of doing `"[*].person"` JsonPath on the whole parsed JSON.

I hope I have understood your question correctly. If not, please let me know =)

**Update:**

Based on your comments I understand what you are after. What you could do is create a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<JToken> GetTokensByPath(TextReader tr, string path)
{
    // do our best to convert the path to a RegEx
    var regex = new Regex(path.Replace("[*]", @"\[[0-9]*\]"));
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(tr))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(reader.Path))
                yield return JToken.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

I am matching the path based on the JSON path input, but we need to try and handle all of the various JSON path grammars, at the moment I'm only support `*`.
This approach will be useful when you have a massive file, with a deep JSON path selector, you'll keep the stream open longer if you enumerate slowly, but you will have a much lower peak memory usage.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You definitely have. In your case, you modified the path as I did. I was hoping that I would be able to make use of the json path upstream (closer to the reader) so I would not have to modify the path. Also by modifying the path, if they gave me [1].person, I'll have to handle the [1] myself. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.